# Refresh iFrame to different source using JavaScript after a specific time

Tags: javascript, html, iframe

I want to load some website inside an iframe initially. After 1 minute, JavaScript will refresh the embedded page to a different page. This is what I have come up with.

```
<html>
<body>
    <IFRAME src="http://firstwebsite.com" width="100%" height="100%" frameBorder="0" id=”myframe”></IFRAME>
    <script>
        setTimeout("document.getElementById('myframe').src = 'http://secondwebsite.com';",6000);
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

This doesn't work though. Please help me fix this very same script rather than giving me new ideas.

Comment: You know 6000 msecs is 6 secs? You need 60000 for a delay of a minute.

Comment: @Teemu is right. See my answer to fix your problem.

Comment: Yeah okay, that's right Teemu. It was a typo. But again the issue wasn't  the time but the script itself. KunJ got me the right fix!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

2 mistakes in your code:

1. Change `”` to `'` or `"` in iframe id and
2. Use 60000 for 1 minute, not 6000.

Rest is OK. Here are edits:

```
<html>
<body>
    <IFRAME src="http://firstwebsite.com" width="100%" height="100%" frameBorder="0" id="myframe"></IFRAME>
    <script>
        setTimeout("document.getElementById('myframe').src = 'http://secondwebsite.com';",60000);
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

you should write setTimeout different.

```
<html>
<body>
    <IFRAME src="http://firstwebsite.com" width="100%" height="100%" frameBorder="0" id=”myframe”></IFRAME>
    <script>
        setTimeout(function(){document.getElementById('myframe').src = 'http://secondwebsite.com';},6000);
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

try `setTimeout(function() { document.frames['myframe'].src = .... }, 6000);`

Answer (score 0):

```
- Change ” to ' or " in the iframe id that you have used.
(id's can only be picked up by " or '.)

- and finally 60000millisec = 60sec = 1min.
```

Check the [fiddle:](http://jsfiddle.net/Fbbn3/2/)

Just updated the time to 5000 if you want to check it out.(You would just have to wait 5sec then)

Basically here's the **short code:**

```
  setTimeout("document.getElementById('myframe').src = 'http://secondwebsite.com';",60000);
```